# Creating Tangent Lines from Intersecting Circles

Tags: geometry, circles

In a discussion with my peers, the following picture was brought up.

[image]

We know that PR and PS will always be tangent lines to Circle C, we just wanted to prove how. We were unable to do such, and I was looking here not for a solution, but for a hint as to where to approach this from.

The construction is pretty straight forward, listed below.

[image]

Comment: What are you starting with?  What construction is indicated here?

Comment: @saulspatz I added it to the question.

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and may not be accessible to those using screen readers.  I don't use a screen reader, but the type is too small for me to read.

Answer (score 1):

Segment PC is diameter, therefore angle PRC is 90 degrees. Segment  CR is radius, QED

Comment: Oh!!!!!!!! Because the diameter is 180 degrees, and it is a chord, the inscribed angle is 90 degrees. I still dont understand why that makes CR a radius though.

Comment: CR is a radius of smaller circle

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw the line segment $CR$ (and similarly, $CS$). Consider the triangle $\triangle PCR$, what can you say about the angle $\angle CRP $?